Stopping repeated XML Headers
SQL Server version:
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB4458842) - 13.0.4224.16 (X64)   
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor) 

I have a need to build a nested XML file that has a top tag of monthlydata, then I need a single header present at the top of the file inside monthlydata. Finally, I have repeated fields nested inside the monthlydata but surrounded by the header.
Here is the table design:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[f_XML_Data]
(
    [SurveyID] [VARCHAR](15) NOT NULL,
    [RecDate] [VARCHAR](15) NOT NULL,
    [DisDate] [VARCHAR](15) NOT NULL,
    [CMS_10] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [CMS_11] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [CMS_23] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [CMS_24] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [CMS_27] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [CMS_30] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [ITADMSRC] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [ITDCGSTA] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [ITDISDAT] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [ITHCAHPS] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [ITSERVIC] [VARCHAR](50) NULL
)

Here is the data:
INSERT INTO dbo.f_XML_Data VALUES ('6561942362','2024-07-10','2024-03-12','Always','Always','8','Definitely yes','Some college','English','1','6','2024-03-12','220090','Storage')
INSERT INTO dbo.f_XML_Data VALUES ('6705168282','2024-07-15','2024-04-10','Always','Always','9','Definitely yes','Some college','English','1','3','2024-04-10','220091','Storage')
INSERT INTO dbo.f_XML_Data VALUES ('6866086131','2024-07-02','2024-05-10','Always','Always','9','Definitely yes','4-yr coll. grad.','English','1','1','2024-05-10','220092','Storage')
INSERT INTO dbo.f_XML_Data VALUES ('6903690620','2024-07-02','2024-05-16','Usually','Always','9','Definitely yes','4-yr coll. grad.','English','1','1','2024-05-16','220093','Removal')
INSERT INTO dbo.f_XML_Data VALUES ('6978329252','2024-07-09','2024-05-21','Always','Always','10-Best possible','Definitely yes','Some college','English','1','1','2024-05-21','220094','Storage')
INSERT INTO dbo.f_XML_Data VALUES ('6978332884','2024-07-09','2024-05-31','Sometimes','Usually','8','Definitely no','NULL','NULL','1','3','2024-05-31','220095','Storage')
INSERT INTO dbo.f_XML_Data VALUES ('6978336149','2024-07-02','2024-05-21','Usually','Always','10-Best possible','Definitely yes','Some college','English','1','6','2024-05-21','220096','Storage')
INSERT INTO dbo.f_XML_Data VALUES ('6978337433','2024-07-16','2024-06-01','Never','Always','6','Probably yes','4-yr coll. grad.','English','1','1','2024-06-01','220097','Removal')
INSERT INTO dbo.f_XML_Data VALUES ('6978344956','2024-07-09','2024-06-01','Always','Usually','8','Probably yes','Some college','NULL','1','3','2024-06-01','220098','Storage')
INSERT INTO dbo.f_XML_Data VALUES ('6978347260','2024-07-12','2024-05-23','Usually','Usually','10-Best possible','Definitely yes','Some college','English','1','6','2024-05-23','220099','Storage')

Here is my current code:
SELECT 
    (SELECT 
         'Forward Design' AS [company-name],
         '782837' AS [client-id],
         main.[SurveyID] AS [SurveyID],
         DATEPART(YEAR, [ITDISDAT]) AS [rsp-yr],
         DATEPART(MONTH, [ITDISDAT]) AS [rsp-month]
     FROM 
         dbo.f_XML_Data hdr
     WHERE 
         hdr.[SurveyID] = main.[SurveyID]
     FOR XML PATH('Header'), TYPE),

    (SELECT 
         (SELECT 
              [ITHCAHPS] AS [surveysub-id],
              DATEPART(YEAR, [ITDISDAT]) AS [rsp-yr],
              DATEPART(MONTH, [ITDISDAT]) AS [rsp-month],
              [ITADMSRC] AS [source],  
              [ITSERVIC] AS [principal-reason],
              [ITDCGSTA] AS [status],  -- Already translated for PG in the file we send
              [CMS_30] AS [language],
              DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST([DisDate] AS DATE), CAST([RecDate] AS DATE)) AS [lag-time],
              '52' AS [supplemental-question-count]
          FROM 
              dbo.f_XML_Data admin
          WHERE 
              admin.[SurveyID] = main.[SurveyID]
          FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('administration'), TYPE),
         (SELECT
              [CMS_10] AS [cleanliness],
              [CMS_11] AS [quiet],
              [CMS_23] AS [overall-rate],
              [CMS_24] AS [recommend],
              [CMS_27] AS [education],
              [CMS_30] AS [language-speak]
          FROM 
              dbo.f_XML_Data admin
          WHERE 
              admin.[SurveyID] = main.[SurveyID]
          FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('response'), TYPE)
      FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('coredata'), TYPE)
FROM 
    dbo.f_XML_Data main
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('monthlydata'), TYPE

This is what I get (first two rows only for brevity):
<monthlydata>
  <Header>
    <company-name>Forward Design</company-name>
    <client-id>782837</client-id>
    <SurveyID>6561942362</SurveyID>
    <rsp-yr>2024</rsp-yr>
    <rsp-month>3</rsp-month>
  </Header>
  <coredata>
    <administration>
      <surveysub-id>220090</surveysub-id>
      <rsp-yr>2024</rsp-yr>
      <rsp-month>3</rsp-month>
      <source>1</source>
      <principal-reason>Storage</principal-reason>
      <status>6</status>
      <language>English</language>
      <lag-time>120</lag-time>
      <supplemental-question-count>52</supplemental-question-count>
    </administration>
    <response>
      <cleanliness>Always</cleanliness>
      <quiet>Always</quiet>
      <overall-rate>8</overall-rate>
      <recommend>Definitely yes</recommend>
      <education>Some college</education>
      <language-speak>English</language-speak>
    </response>
  </coredata>
  <Header>
    <company-name>Forward Design</company-name>
    <client-id>782837</client-id>
    <SurveyID>6561942362</SurveyID>
    <rsp-yr>2024</rsp-yr>
    <rsp-month>4</rsp-month>
  </Header>
  <coredata>
    <administration>
      <surveysub-id>220091</surveysub-id>
      <rsp-yr>2024</rsp-yr>
      <rsp-month>4</rsp-month>
      <source>1</source>
      <principal-reason>Storage</principal-reason>
      <status>3</status>
      <language>English</language>
      <lag-time>96</lag-time>
      <supplemental-question-count>52</supplemental-question-count>
    </administration>
    <response>
      <cleanliness>Always</cleanliness>
      <quiet>Always</quiet>
      <overall-rate>9</overall-rate>
      <recommend>Definitely yes</recommend>
      <education>Some college</education>
      <language-speak>English</language-speak>
    </response>
  </coredata>
</monthlydata>

This is what I would like to get(Again, first two rows only):
<monthlydata>
  <Header>
    <company-name>Forward Design</company-name>
    <client-id>782837</client-id>
    <SurveyID>6561942362</SurveyID>
    <rsp-yr>2024</rsp-yr>
    <rsp-month>3</rsp-month>
  <coredata>
    <administration>
      <surveysub-id>220090</surveysub-id>
      <rsp-yr>2024</rsp-yr>
      <rsp-month>3</rsp-month>
      <source>1</source>
      <principal-reason>Storage</principal-reason>
      <status>6</status>
      <language>English</language>
      <lag-time>120</lag-time>
      <supplemental-question-count>52</supplemental-question-count>
    </administration>
    <response>
      <cleanliness>Always</cleanliness>
      <quiet>Always</quiet>
      <overall-rate>8</overall-rate>
      <recommend>Definitely yes</recommend>
      <education>Some college</education>
      <language-speak>English</language-speak>
    </response>
  </coredata>
  <coredata>
    <administration>
      <surveysub-id>220091</surveysub-id>
      <rsp-yr>2024</rsp-yr>
      <rsp-month>4</rsp-month>
      <source>1</source>
      <principal-reason>Storage</principal-reason>
      <status>3</status>
      <language>English</language>
      <lag-time>96</lag-time>
      <supplemental-question-count>52</supplemental-question-count>
    </administration>
    <response>
      <cleanliness>Always</cleanliness>
      <quiet>Always</quiet>
      <overall-rate>9</overall-rate>
      <recommend>Definitely yes</recommend>
      <education>Some college</education>
      <language-speak>English</language-speak>
    </response>
  </coredata>
  </Header>
</monthlydata>

Hope that is what you all are looking for. I really would like to avoid doing string concatenation if possible.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

In its current state the question is unanswerable. You really need to provide ##1-4. Beyond that there is no string concatenation in your T-SQL

And you really need to tag the question with the technology you are using, rather than leaving us to work it out by reading your code.

It is not clear how you want to collapse first two rows of data into one single Header.  The SurveyID=6561942362 is in the desired output, but the SurveyID=6705168282 is gone from the desired output. Based on what criteria is the grouping?

Correct, Yitzhak, that is my fault.  I am trying to avoid using identifying data due to the legal stuff.  I have corrected so the SurveyID is the same.  Apologies for confusion.

I am trying to understand what you are after, but I don't see the corrected data. Please fix it.

You only want to add header the first time in the loop.  So you need an IF statement around the Header section and a variable so you only enter the Header section the first time in the loop.

Please try the following solution.
I had to adjust sample data to allow grouping based on two columns: SurveyID and ITDISDAT that are in the XML's Header fragment.
SQL
DECLARE @f_XML_Data TABLE (
    [SurveyID] [VARCHAR](15) NOT NULL,
    [RecDate] [VARCHAR](15) NOT NULL,
    [DisDate] [VARCHAR](15) NOT NULL,
    [CMS_10] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [CMS_11] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [CMS_23] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [CMS_24] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [CMS_27] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [CMS_30] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [ITADMSRC] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [ITDCGSTA] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [ITDISDAT] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [ITHCAHPS] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [ITSERVIC] [VARCHAR](50) NULL);

INSERT @f_XML_Data VALUES
('6561942362','2024-07-10','2024-03-12','Always','Always','8','Definitely yes','Some college','English','1','6','2024-03-12','220090','Storage'),
('6561942362','2024-07-15','2024-04-10','Always','Always','9','Definitely yes','Some college','English','1','3','2024-03-12','220091','Storage');
--('6866086131','2024-07-02','2024-05-10','Always','Always','9','Definitely yes','4-yr coll. grad.','English','1','1','2024-05-10','220092','Storage'),
--('6903690620','2024-07-02','2024-05-16','Usually','Always','9','Definitely yes','4-yr coll. grad.','English','1','1','2024-05-16','220093','Removal'),
--('6978329252','2024-07-09','2024-05-21','Always','Always','10-Best possible','Definitely yes','Some college','English','1','1','2024-05-21','220094','Storage'),
--('6978332884','2024-07-09','2024-05-31','Sometimes','Usually','8','Definitely no','NULL','NULL','1','3','2024-05-31','220095','Storage'),
--('6978336149','2024-07-02','2024-05-21','Usually','Always','10-Best possible','Definitely yes','Some college','English','1','6','2024-05-21','220096','Storage'),
--('6978337433','2024-07-16','2024-06-01','Never','Always','6','Probably yes','4-yr coll. grad.','English','1','1','2024-06-01','220097','Removal'),
--('6978344956','2024-07-09','2024-06-01','Always','Usually','8','Probably yes','Some college','NULL','1','3','2024-06-01','220098','Storage'),
--('6978347260','2024-07-12','2024-05-23','Usually','Usually','10-Best possible','Definitely yes','Some college','English','1','6','2024-05-23','220099','Storage');

SELECT * FROM @f_XML_Data;

SELECT 'Forward Design' AS [company-name]
    , '782837' AS [client-id]
    , [SurveyID] AS [SurveyID]
    , YEAR(ITDISDAT) AS [rsp-yr]
    , MONTH(ITDISDAT) AS [rsp-month],
    (
    SELECT [ITHCAHPS] AS [administration/surveysub-id]
        , YEAR(ITDISDAT) AS [administration/rsp-yr]
        , MONTH(ITDISDAT) AS [administration/rsp-month]
        ,[ITADMSRC] AS [administration/source]
        ,[ITSERVIC] AS [administration/principal-reason]
        ,[ITDCGSTA] AS [administration/status]  -- Already translated for PG in the file we send
        ,[CMS_30] AS [administration/language]
        , DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST([DisDate] AS DATE), CAST([RecDate] AS DATE)) AS [administration/lag-time]
        ,'52' AS [administration/supplemental-question-count]
        , [CMS_10] AS [response/cleanliness]
        ,[CMS_11] AS [response/quiet]
        ,[CMS_23] AS [response/overall-rate]
        ,[CMS_24] AS [response/recommend]
        ,[CMS_27] AS [response/education]
        ,[CMS_30] AS [response/language-speak]
    FROM @f_XML_Data AS child
    WHERE parent.SurveyID = child.SurveyID
    FOR XML PATH('coredata'), TYPE
)
FROM @f_XML_Data AS parent
GROUP BY parent.SurveyID, parent.ITDISDAT
FOR XML PATH('Header'), TYPE, ROOT('monthlydata');

Output
<monthlydata>
  <Header>
    <company-name>Forward Design</company-name>
    <client-id>782837</client-id>
    <SurveyID>6561942362</SurveyID>
    <rsp-yr>2024</rsp-yr>
    <rsp-month>3</rsp-month>
    <coredata>
      <administration>
        <surveysub-id>220090</surveysub-id>
        <rsp-yr>2024</rsp-yr>
        <rsp-month>3</rsp-month>
        <source>1</source>
        <principal-reason>Storage</principal-reason>
        <status>6</status>
        <language>English</language>
        <lag-time>120</lag-time>
        <supplemental-question-count>52</supplemental-question-count>
      </administration>
      <response>
        <cleanliness>Always</cleanliness>
        <quiet>Always</quiet>
        <overall-rate>8</overall-rate>
        <recommend>Definitely yes</recommend>
        <education>Some college</education>
        <language-speak>English</language-speak>
      </response>
    </coredata>
    <coredata>
      <administration>
        <surveysub-id>220091</surveysub-id>
        <rsp-yr>2024</rsp-yr>
        <rsp-month>3</rsp-month>
        <source>1</source>
        <principal-reason>Storage</principal-reason>
        <status>3</status>
        <language>English</language>
        <lag-time>96</lag-time>
        <supplemental-question-count>52</supplemental-question-count>
      </administration>
      <response>
        <cleanliness>Always</cleanliness>
        <quiet>Always</quiet>
        <overall-rate>9</overall-rate>
        <recommend>Definitely yes</recommend>
        <education>Some college</education>
        <language-speak>English</language-speak>
      </response>
    </coredata>
  </Header>
</monthlydata>


Thanks Yitzhak, that appears to function well.

Glad to be helpful.
